# Spring SpEL: how to base the value of one property on another

Tags: spring, spring-el

I would like to set the value of 2 properties in a Spring boot application, where the second one is strictly based on the first one.

```
@Value("${main.propertyOne: 0.67}")
 void setPropertyOne(float propertyOne) {
    this.propertyOne = propertyOne;
 }

@Value("#{${main.propertyTwo:(${main.propertyOne: 0.67} + 0.10)}}")
 void setPropertyTwo(float propertyTwo) {
     this.propertyTwo = propertyTwo;
 }
```

With this approach, `propertyOne` is always correctly set to its default value (0.67) or to the one that I set in the property file, but `propertyTwo` is either the value that I set on the property file (which is fine) or 0.77. In practice, it is never actually based on the value of `propertyOne`.

The behavior I would like is:

- If `propertyOne` is set to 0.48 and `propertyTwo` is not set, then it defaults to 0.48 + 0.10= 0.58
- If `propertyOne` is not set, then it defaults to 0.67 and `propertyTwo` defaults to 0.67 + 0.10 = 0.77

Is it something that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@Value("#{${main.propertyTwo:(T(Float).parseFloat('${main.propertyOne: 0.67}') + 0.10)}}")
```

Comment: The result is still 0.77 (so it is ignoring the value of `main.propertyOne`)

Comment: No; I tested it; with propertyOne set to `.23`, I get `0.33`.